# Can rings in the signature $(+,*,0,1)$ be axiomatized by universal sentences?

Tags: ring-theory, model-theory

In the signature $(+,-,*,0,1)$, rings can be axiomatized by $\forall$-sentences. What about in the signature $(+,*,0,1)$? I believe they cannot, because you need an existential quantifier to state that every element has an additive inverse. But perhaps they can still be axiomatized by using another set of $\forall$-sentences. So, my question is, can the theory of rings in the signature $(+,*,0,1)$ be axiomatized by only $\forall$-sentences?

Comment: See my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131666/242) for some conceptual background on such matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a class of algebras axiomatized by universal sentences is closed under subalgebras. But the subalgebra $\mathbb{N}$ in the signature $(+,*,0,1)$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a ring.